# Every Lebesgue measurable function is equal almost everywhere to a Borel measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that this question was asked before but I have a doubt in a technique that I usually use, I will say what it is after.

The Problem: Prove that for every Lebesgue measurable function $f$ there exists a measurable Borel function $g$ such that $f=g$ almost everywhere.

All functions that we consider have $\mathbb{R}^n$ as domain and extended real numbers as codomain or a subset of it. Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure.

I already prove that for every simple function (here simple functions are measurable) the problem is true.

Let $f$ be a measurable nonnegative function. There exists a sequence $ \{ \varphi_k \}_{k=1}^\infty$ of nonnegative simple functions such that
\begin{align*}
\varphi_1 \leqslant \varphi_2 \leqslant \varphi_3 \leqslant \cdots 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \varphi_k(x)
\end{align*}

For what I know from before, for every $\varphi_k$ there exists a Borel measurable function $g_k$ such that $\varphi_k = g_k$ almost everywhere. Let's do
\begin{align*}
Z_k = \{ \varphi_k \neq g_k \}
\end{align*}
then $m(Z_k) = 0$.

Now consider the next function:
\begin{align*}
g(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \inf g_k(x)
\end{align*}
and $g$ is a Borel measurable function. We want to proof that $f = g$ a.e. For that
\begin{align*}
x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty Z_k^c & \Rightarrow \forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \ \varphi_k(x) = g_k(x) 
\\
& \Rightarrow \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \varphi_k(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \varphi_k(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \inf g_k(x)
\\
& \Rightarrow f(x) = g(x)
\end{align*}

And my doubt is if my conclusion is correct: $f(x) \neq g(x) \Rightarrow x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty Z_k$. In words, $f$ and $g$ are different when $x$ is in a subset of $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty Z_k$, wich has zero measure because the Lebesgue measure is complete (and then are equal a.e).

I know that logically speaken my conclusion is true, but I don't know, is like I "feel" something is wrong.